# Is there any formula to get the date only?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, copy-paste, excel-2019

Is there any formula to copy the date "10/13/2022  12:30:00 AM" but just get the date only?

Like: 10/13/2022

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If your date-time is in A1 then just `=Int(A1)` trims out the time portion. Just format it to show the date...

Comment: wow that's great! it works perfectly as I would like! I also added to my Macro. Thank you very much @Chris Maurer.

Comment: Excel only really has two data types, numbers and text.  Dates are floating point numbers whose integer part is the number of days since 1/1/1900, and whose fractional part is the fraction of the day.  This allows some interesting arithmetic such as `mod(date,7)` giving the day of the week.

Comment: nice, it is great to know! thank you once again!